# Testing page transitions using Qunit

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

I have a `popstate` handler to handle page transitions without page reloads and I am using Qunit as a testing framework.  The problem is that the popstate events fire asynchronously and in my tests I need to wait for the event to complete before running the assertions.  Currently, I am using `setTimeout`, waiting a second and then running the assertions.  This is fragile and I want to avoid it.

Here is something like the code I am trying to test:

```
asyncTest("Transition1", function() {
    setUpPage(pageState1);
    assertPageState(pageState1);
    setUpPage(pageState2);
    assertPageState(pageState2);
    history.back();
    setTimeout(function() {
        assertPageState(pageState1);
    }, 1000);
});
```

I have thought about registering another popstate handler for the test, but I don't know if I am guaranteed that the test handler will always run after the original handler.  Also, not sure how to unregister handlers (this is just because I am a jquery novice).